# How can I replace a number with one higher

Tags: bash, macos, sed

I have a bash script for macOS, which replaces the last character (a number) on the first line of a document with the number plus one. For example, if the number was 19, it would be replaced with 20 (I know that the code only replaces the last character). Here's the code that I currently have:

```sh
#For some reason the -e (not -E) is necessary here
RC01=$(sed -ne "1s/.*\(.\)$/\1/p" ./document)
RC02=${RC01}
let "RC02++"
sed -i '' -n "1s/${RC01}/${RC02}/" ./document
```

When the last line runs, if the document has a first line with anything on it, it clears the whole document.

What's going wrong, and how can I fix it?

Comment: Is `sed` a requirement?  Something like `awk` may end up being easier.

Comment: @0x5453 would awk work properly and the same on macOS/OS X 10.11-11.0?

Comment: Do you literally want to replace only the last character, so that the next number after 19 is 110?

Comment: I hadn't thought about that. I want to replace the number at the end of the line, so 19 would become 20 @tripleee

Comment: Awk would be much superior to `sed`, yes, including on macOS.'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your immediate problem is that `sed -n` suppresses all printing of output lines.

You can fix this easily by removing the `-n`;

```sh
RC01=$(sed -n "1s/.*\(.\)$/\1/p" ./document)
RC02=${RC01}
let "RC02++"
sed -i '' "1s/${RC01}\$/${RC02}/" ./document
```

This still has the problem that you only increment the very last digit; if your number has more than one digit, this will lead to weirdness like 18, 19, 110, 111 rather than 18, 19, 20, 21

```sh
RC01=$(sed -n "s/\(.*[^0-9]\)\([0-9]*\)$/\2/p;q" ./document)
RC02=${RC01}
let "RC02++"
sed -i '' "1s/${RC01}\$/${RC02}/" ./document
```

The `-i` feature of `sed` is hard to beat for replacing a file in place.  If it weren't for that, I would definitely recommend Awk instead.  Here's a quick attempt.

```sh
awk 'NR == 1 { $NF = 1+$NF }1' ./document >./document.tmp &&
mv ./document.tmp ./document
```

Perl has the best of both worlds, with sugar on top;

```sh
perl -pi -e 's/(\d+)$/1+$1/e if $. == 1' ./document
```

Comment: Would `RC01=$(sed -n "2s/\(.*[^0-9]\)\([0-9]*\)$/\2/p;q" ./document)` work for finding the number(s) at the end of the second line?

Comment: I tried your exact answer for the first line, but noticed that you didn’t put anything (such as a 1) before the /s. I wasn’t sure if it’d still work if I stuck a 2 or a different number before it.

Comment: I reorganized it to quit after printing, so the line number became redundant for the first line. So yeah, correction, it won't work with just the line number added. Try `2!d;s/\(.*[^0-9]\)\([0-9]*\)$/\2/p;q`

Comment: And the last line, `sed -i '' "2s/${RC01}\$/${RC02}/" ./document` will work as is, right?

Comment: Yeah, that should work straight off. Some experimentation without `-i ''` should hopefully help prove that.

Comment: What does the `\$` in the last do?

Comment: It matches end of line. The backslash is not strictly necessary here, but it hopefully convinces the human reader that we don't want the shell to interpret the dollar sign, but rather pass it through to `sed` as part of the regex.

Comment: Ahhh, thanks, I now know why one instance of this didn’t work